# Py2Exe "The following modules are missing"

Tags: python, py2exe

When using Py2Exe, I get a warning such as

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['Crypto', 'Crypto.Cipher', 'Crypto.Hash', 'Padding']
```

The resulting EXE errors because it cannot find those modules. I can see they are in my site-packages, so why is it not detecting them?

Note: Crypto and Padding were installed through pip/easy_install

Answer (score 4):

**First, check if your packages are in .EGG format**

It appears Py2Exe has problems with Python's .egg packages. By extracting the .egg files (rename to .zip and extract into site-packages excluding EGG-INFO folder), Py2Exe can now detect those packages without issues.

**Check your setup.py to make sure you're using the right option. Windowed applications use "windows=" where-as console applications use "console="**

In some other cases it could be through the use of `setup(console=['main.py'])` instead of `setup(windows=['main.py'])` if you're producing a windowed application.

**If it's still not working, you can try telling Py2Exe to manually include the package**

Some packages can further be resolved by adding them to the package options of your setup.py like this:

```
setup(
    windows=['main.py'],
    options={
            "py2exe":{
                    "packages": ["Crypto", "Padding"]
            }
    }
```