# Py2exe Adding package ( e.g. Carbon ) to exe

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe, paramiko

I create a script where i used this imports :

```
import MySQLdb
import sys
import paramiko as pm
import os
```

Now i try to convert this script to .exe with py2exe and this setup.py :

```
# setup.py 
from distutils.core import setup
import os
import MySQLdb
import sys
import paramiko
import py2exe

data_files = []
setup(
    name='Worker',
    console=['Script.py'], 
    options={ 
        'py2exe': {
            'packages': [],
            'dist_dir': 'dist', 
            'compressed': True, 
            'includes': ['paramiko', 'MySQLdb'], 
        }
    },

    data_files=data_files 

)
```

Part from the Log if I run the setup   :

```
The following modules appear to be missing
['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', '_imp', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', '_thread', 'builtins', 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._commoncrypto', 'gssapi', 'importlib.machinery', 'pkg_resources.extern.appdirs', '
pkg_resources.extern.packaging', 'pkg_resources.extern.six', 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves', 'sspi', 'sspicon', 'win32pipe', 'winreg']

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.
```

It create a exe, but if i try to run this I get the error that the modules missing.
So how I can add this modules to my exe/setup.py ?

Comment: try adding `'Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', '_imp', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', '_thread', 'builtins', 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._commoncrypto', 'gssapi', 'importlib.machinery', 'pkg_resources.extern.appdirs', '
pkg_resources.extern.packaging', 'pkg_resources.extern.six', 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves', 'sspi', 'sspicon', 'win32pipe', 'winreg'` in empty packages key in your setup.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Running this code:

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import os
import MySQLdb
import sys
import paramiko
import py2exe

data_files = []
setup(
    name='Worker',
    console=['Script.py'], 
    options={ 
        'py2exe': {
            'packages': ['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', '_imp', '_scproxy', '_sysconfigdata', '_thread', 'builtins', 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._commoncrypto', 'gssapi', 'importlib.machinery', 'pkg_resources.extern.appdirs', ' pkg_resources.extern.packaging', 'pkg_resources.extern.six', 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves', 'sspi', 'sspicon', 'win32pipe', 'winreg'],
            'dist_dir': 'dist', 
            'compressed': True, 
            'includes': ['paramiko', 'MySQLdb'], 
        }
    },

    data_files=data_files 

)
```

I took the reference from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436591/py2exe-the-following-modules-are-missing).

Comment: Now i get the Error : ImportError: No module named Carbon

Comment: Try to install Carbon module. And If possible edit your question with your script code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.  From what I can see, Carbon requires "graphite" and that's *nix only!  Therefore, there is no easy resolution for any of this on Windows with py2exe...